# codeblocks error on win7 64bits

Tags: save, codeblocks, configuration-files

I'd like to try CodeBlocks for c++ learning, but there is a problem:

Everytime I close CodeBlocks and exit to the windows desktop, there is two messeages: "unable to open personal dictionary file."  "Couldn't save config file."

no matter which version I use, 13.12  15.12 16.01

Is there anyone can help me!
I'm really appreciate it!

Answer (score 6):

Execute `codeblocks.exe` instead of `CbLauncher.exe` and the problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem.

The reason is that: My computer had installed CB before, and I uninstall it, but it left some files on my computer. So when I installed CB 16.01 somedays before, it had error, beacuse there is already file.

I think it should be improved, and can handle the situation.

Answer (score 0):

try installing or unzipping codeblocks to another harddisk, say d:/ or e:/ rather than c:/